# Why does my sricpt starts 2 notepads?

Tags: foreach, vbscript, do-while

Why does my script start two notepad instances without waiting for the user to close the first notepad? I would like that my script opens one text file, than waits for closing of notepad before it opens the next one.

```
set service = GetObject ("winmgmts:")
Dim ArchiveList
Dim ExportTool
Dim running

ExportTool = "notepad.exe "    
ArchiveList = Array("A.txt","b.txt")

For Each element In ArchiveList
    Dim objShell
    Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    objShell.Run(ExportTool & element)
    running = true
    WScript.Sleep 3000

    Do while running
        running = false
        for each Process in Service.InstancesOf ("Win32_Process")
            If Process.Name = ExportTool then
                running = true
            End If
        next
    Loop
    MsgBox "Hallo Erdling", VBOKOnly, "Muhaha"
    ' not running
Next
```

I do not understand why this is not working.

Comment: `"notepad.exe "` How the process name will be equal to a variable with a space at the end?

Comment: would like to give you the point for the info :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`running` is never set to `True` by your `For Each Process` loop as the `ExportTool` value will not be found in the Services List due to the extra space.

Remove the space and add it where you concatenate the `ExportTool` and `element` values:

```
set service = GetObject ("winmgmts:")
Dim ArchiveList
Dim ExportTool
Dim running

ExportTool = "notepad.exe"    ' remove trailing space
ArchiveList = Array("A.txt","b.txt")

For Each element In ArchiveList
    Dim objShell
    Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    objShell.Run(ExportTool & " " &  element) ' add space
    running = true
    WScript.Sleep 3000

    Do while running
        running = false
        for each Process in Service.InstancesOf ("Win32_Process")
            If Process.Name = ExportTool then
                running = true
            End If
        next
    Loop
    MsgBox "Hallo Erdling", VBOKOnly, "Muhaha"
    ' not running
Next
```

Should work now.

Answer (score -1):

Because

```
ArchiveList = Array("A.txt","b.txt")
```

creates an array with two elements, so that the loop starting with

```
For Each element In ArchiveList
```

will run for element = "A.txt" and element = "B.txt" and

```
objShell.Run(ExportTool & element)
```

will .Run Notepad.exe for each text file.

Comment: The OP question states this is the intended behaviour, to start two instances, BUT to wait for the first to end before starting the second. It is the `Process` loop what fails.

Comment: @MCND - you are right. Went straight from the question to the code.